# how to trigger bootstrap5 data-bs-dismiss using JavaScript inside a function in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to close/hide bootstrap5 modal using JavaScript in angular, the problem that the hide function in bootstrap notworking somehow, so what I'm trying to do is to click a button that have data-bs-dismiss and it's work if I click it manually but not working if I try to do it via JavaScript.

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="#modalId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
    data-toggle="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-body">
                    <button id="modalDismiss" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Test</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
document.getElementById('modalDismiss').click(); // notwoking
new window.bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('modalId')).hide(); //trying this same problem :(
new window.bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('modalId')).show(); //trying to show the modal works fine idon't why the hide function not working for me.
```

> I trace the click event for the `modalDismiss` and found that the event that close the modal
> [image]

I don't know if this relevant to the problem.

Comment: Don't use bootstrap JS in angular, There the separate good package for angular bootstrap i.g. ng-bootstrap check that.

Comment: I can't use another library 'cause the website already built on bootstrap5

Comment: @MahmoudSkafi how do you want to close modal ?

Comment: I need to close modal via JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

complete demo in this [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n1khws?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Basically, you need to import modal class from `import { Modal } from 'bootstrap';` .

when Modal opened then you need to assign modal reference to this modal class and then create new instance.

```
 open(element: any): void {
   this.modalDirect = new Modal(element, {});
   this.modalDirect.show();
 }
```

and then, when you click on close button then call this close method.

```
close() {
  this.modalDirect.hide();
}
```

complete code you can find out in attached stackblitz lik.

Answer (score 0):

so i believe you have atleast 1 dismissal button in your modal.

you can do this on handleSubmit or whereever you want to dismiss that

```
const closeButton = form.querySelector('[data-bs-dismiss="modal"]');
        if (closeButton) {
          closeButton.click();
        }
```

this is the best way of closing or dismissal of modal